# php ternary operator confusion

Tags: php, if-statement, ternary-operator

This is making me lose my mind, so please help:

```
$param[] = ($k == 'page') ? (($i > 1) ? "{$k}-{$i}" : null) : "{$k}-{$v}";
```

what I want is:

```
if ($k == 'page')
    if ($i > 1)
        $param[] = "{$k}-{$i}";
    else
        $param[] = null;
else
    $param[] = "{$k}-{$v}";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you kill kittens like that?

Comment: Are you really trying insert string value "{$k}-{$v}" into $param array?

Comment: Stay with the more verbose control structures. Easy-to-understand far outweighs "less lines of code".

Comment: Why not just use the multi-line version?

Comment: It should *sigh* work.. maybe you need $k === 'page'. You should tell us what it going wrong

Comment: Looks like sbagdat answered you already, but I wouldn't use the ternary operator for complex logic.  It's going to be a pain to maintain and if anyone else is looking at your code it's going to take them longer to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @ngen, yes, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: @SorinButurugeanu stacking ternary operator is just bad practice... I'm reading your code over and over... And I've written the same based on your if statement... What it should do and doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, is this clearer:

```
$param[] = ($k == 'page') ? ( ($i > 1) : 'page-'.$i : null ) : $k.'-'.$v;
```

Do you actually want to insert null, though?

**EDIT:**

I **think** you want this:

```
($k == 'page' && $i > 1) ? $params[] = 'page-'.$i : $params[] = $k.'-'.$v;
```

or

```
$params[] = ('page' == $k && 1 < $i) ? 'page-'.$i : $k.'-'.$v;
```

But!  Don't do it.

Instead just keep it simple and do:

```
if('page' == $k && 1 < $i) {
 // some comment
 $params[] = 'page-'.$i;
} else {
 // some comment
 $params[] = $k.'-'.$v;
}
```

Comment: no, actually I don't, but how would I skip inserting something in a chained ternary?

Answer (score 3):

First of all quote from php manual on [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

> It is recommended that you avoid "stacking" ternary expressions. PHP's
>   behaviour when using more than one ternary operator within a single
>   statement is non-obvious

That's what if statement is for... When you will need to read the code again later you'll have problems... But if you insist:

```
$param[] = (($k == 'page') ? (($i > 1) ? "{$k}-{$i}" : null) : "{$k}-{$v}")
```

**Always** use brackets in those cases.

Comment: You really don't need to bracket to that extent. What purpose does bracketing the entire assignment serve anyways? Doesn't improve readability at all.

Comment: @Kenaniah I've overlooked brackets around `($i > 1) ? "{$k}-{$i}" : nul` in his question